# Square root of the square of the cosine: absolute value or not

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, absolute-value

Given the following function we find its derivative:

$$a) \frac{d}{dx}\left[\arcsin(\sin(x))\right] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - \sin^2(x)}}\cos(x) = \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{\cos^2(x)}} = \frac{\cos(x)}{|\cos(x)|}$$

It is important to notice that in the last step the square root of the square resulted in the absolute value, which makes sense if we check the graph of $\arcsin(\sin(x))$.

Now, the we try to find another integral:

$$b) \int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x - a)(b - x)}}$$

Here we use the substitution

$$ x - a = (b - a)\sin^2(u), dx = 2(b - a)\sin(u)\cos(u)du$$

I do not know why this particular substitution was chosen, except that it is hinted at by Apostol. So, with this substitution it is easy to find:

$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{(x - a)(b - x)}} = \frac{2(b - a)\sin(u)\cos(u)}{\sqrt{(b - a)\sin^2(u)(b - a)\cos^2(u)}}du = \frac{2(b - a)}{|b - a|}\int \frac{\sin(u)\cos(u)}{\sin(u)\cos(u)}du$$

which is then trivial. It is important that here $\sqrt{\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x)} = \sin(x)\cos(x)$ unlike in (a), and $\sin/\cos$ themselves are pulled out, not their absolute values!

What is the difference in (a), and (b)? I do not understand why in (b) we are allowed to pull out non-absolute value $\sqrt{\cos^2(x)\sin^2(x)} = \sin(x)\cos(x)$, while it should be like in (a).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function $(b-a)\sin^2 u$ is not one-to-one. So in order to make the substitution $x-a=(b-a)\sin^2 u$ you have to restrict the domain of $\sin^2 u$: otherwise, you won't know which value of $u$ corresponds to a given $x$.

The most natural choice of domain where $(b-a)\sin^2 u$ is one-to-one is the interval $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. Since $(b-a)\sin^2 u$ attains its full range for $u$ in this domain, there is no harm in restricting $u$ to this domain when making the substitution.

But on this interval, $\sin u \cos u$ is nonnegative, because $\sin u$ and $\cos u$ are individually non-negative. So it is genuinely true that $\sqrt{\sin^2 u \cos^2 u}=\sin u \cos u$, without absolute values.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it finally. Took me a while to digest the restriction part: so it seems that we are assured that there exists a $u \in [0, \pi/2]$, s.t. the substitution is correct. I was a little unclear about the result - the integration result is $u$ (before back-substitution of $x$), so it does not indicate any restriction explicitly. But in fact, there is an implicit restriction on $u$ (the result of integration) - it is in the first quadrant?

Comment: I am also really interested how you think about this example. Is there some kind of algorithm you use to check these domains, or every such integral is generally a novelty, so that you have to recheck the domains? I really liked you reasoning about the domain-range of $(b-a)sin^2(u)$ - very clear and coherent. What is it that I regularly need to check to ensure there is no blunder with absolute values?

Comment: I don't know if you can make it totally algorithmic, but there are some useful points to keep in mind. One is that the absolute value function is not differentiable, so it can only show up if either the integrand is discontinuous or its domain is disconnected. In this case, the integrand is continuous on a connected domain ($a < x < b$ or vice versa), so the absolute values must all drop out somehow. In general you should start to worry more about absolute values when you're making secant substitutions, because they tend to correlate with disconnected domains.

Comment: For example, if your integrand involves a $\sqrt{x^2-1}$, you might have to treat the domains $x \ge 1$ and $x \le -1$ separately. The other point is that definite integrals are often easier to understand than indefinite integrals. If you ever find yourself getting confused by this sort of issue, it's helpful to think through what would happen if you added limits of integration to the problem. (What values could they take? What would happen to those values after you made the substitution? And so on...)

Comment: Nice advice, thank you, Micah! :)

Answer (score 3):

Note that in the second integral, if you are using real numbers, then $a\le x\le b$ or $b\le x\le a$ (otherwise the argument of the square root is negative). The the substitution you are making implies $0\le u\le \pi/2$, so both $\sin$ and $\cos$ have positive values.